# opening a mdb file password protected by Busy Win

Tags: database, ms-access, passwords

I am using an accounting software named BusyWin for almost an year. I set up an admin password in the software.  It created two password protected mdb files for storing records. Somehow my database got corrupted(the busywin is giving the error saying it is corrupted; access is just asking for the password), now I am unable to open the same with the busywin software. I also tried to open the mdb file using access but it looks like the password is not same as the one used in BusyWin.

I contacted the developers of BusyWin and they agreed to repair the file for some amount but they are asking me to send the mdb files to their office. The data I have is highly confidential and I cant trust anyone with that.

Please let me know if there is any way to either recover the file or to derive the password from the admin password I have.

Comment: What reason would these developers have to compromise your data? Just send them the data -- they are the only ones who can fix it.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: If you sign an agreement with your customers saying their information will be kept private, it doesn't matter if each record is worth a million bucks or just plain embarrassing. You don't share it with someone outside of your company.

Comment: The developers of BusyWin are not going to look at your data. Either you're being an idiot now for not trusting them, or you were an idiot for trusting them when you chose the software. Your choice.

Comment: This question needs a proper tag 'BusyWin' or 'Busy-accounting-software' in order to make it identifiable. Anybody with atleast 1500 reputation points or more please make it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution, i use this long many year ago. Please follow the some steps:-

1. First of all backup of your mdb file to other location.
2. Now click on your backuped mdb file.
3. It asking for password, enter the password : ILoveMyINDIA
4. File open in MS-Access check the table for USERS & ADMIN
5. Now close the file without saving.

reply me: moryasanjay@gmail.com

Comment: This is 'the' answer!!! It really opened up a lot of additional useful options for me - like customized reports which were missing in Busy Accounting software